# "And Moses wrote down all the words of the Lord"

Tags: exodus, moses, covenant

In Exodus 24:4 (NASB)

> And Moses wrote down all the words of the Lord. (...)

What are "the words of the Lord"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the giving of the Israelite covenant in Ex 19-23, we have a number of time where God speaks to Moses directly:

- Ex 19:3, 9, 10, etc.

However, the more significant sentence is described as follows:

- Ex 20:1 - "And God spoke all these words:" See Ex 20:1-17 (ie 10 Commandments)
- Ex Ex 20:22 - "Then the LORD spoke to Moses, 'tell the Israelites this'" See Ex 20:23 - 23:33 (Expansion and cultic application of the 10 Commandments)

We are then told (Ex 24:4), **And Moses wrote down all the words of the LORD.**  The people answered, three times, “whatever the Lord has said we will do”, Ex 19:8, 24:3, 7, thus creating the Israelite covenant.

This is clearly what we now have recorded as the covenant and called "the Book of the Covenant" in Ex 24:7.  The 10 Commandments are also called “the covenant” (Ex 34:27, 28, Deut 9:9, 11, 15) and placed inside the ark (Ex 25:16, 21, 40:20, Heb 9:4).

Answer (score 2):

https://biblehub.com/commentaries/exodus/24-4.htm

Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible

> And Moses wrote all the words of the Lord,.... Jarchi says, all from the creation, to the giving of the law, and the commands at Marah; but though these were written by him, yet not at this time; but as Aben Ezra more truly observes, what are mentioned in this "parashah", or **section, or what is contained in the two preceding chapters**, he not only related to them from his memory, but he wrote them in a book, which is after mentioned, that they might be seen and read hereafter; for **these were not the ten commands**, they were written as well as spoken by the Lord himself, but the judicial laws before mentioned